# How might one use the Amazon Product API to get a list of unreleased items?

Tags: php, api, amazon-product-api

This one's been giving me a headache for a while now.  There is one similar question around here, but it's somewhat ambiguous and appears to be unresolved.

I would like to use Amazon's product API to find items in various categories that have yet to be released, that is, items which have a release date which is greater than today's date.  From what I can make of it, there may be a way of getting the release date as a response to a query about an item, but I would prefer to make it a part of the query.  It's simply impractical to request all of the items in a category and check their release dates individually.

The goal is to get the ASINs of every item on a page such as [this one](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_p_n_publication_date_2?rh=n:283155,n%3a!1000,n:4,n:2787,p_n_publication_date:1250228011&bbn=2787&ie=UTF8&qid=1344660178&rnid=1250225011), which is a list of unreleased children's books about animals.  This is just an example, of course.

I'd prefer a PHP solution, but really, anything will do.  Please feel free to ask me to clarify any points if need be.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ItemSearch](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html) operation on the [Product Advertising API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html) with the following parameters:

```
# Specify the SearchIndex  
SearchIndex = 'Books'

# and the category you want to look at. 
BrowseNode = '2787'

# Use the Power parameter to search for items that will be published
# in the future (here: between January 2013 and June 2013)
Power = 'pubdate:after 01 2013 and pubdate:before 06 2013'
```

Read more about the [Power Search Syntax](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/PowerSearchSyntax.html)

Comment: This looks interesting, thanks.  It seems that "pubdate" only works on books and similar items.  Is there an equivalent way of searching other categories as well?  Books are only a small part of what I'm after.

Comment: Unfortunately, Power can only be used when the search index equals Books and I am not aware of any ways to search other categories.